How to resolve "Warning: Error in if: argument is of length zero"
I was trying to draw a spider plot with select widget so it updates the graph with different group has been chosen.
I was able to generate the plot and make selections with no issue. However I kept receiving the Warning: Error in if: argument is of length zero.
I am pasting the reproducible codes ui.R and server.R below:
ui.R
library("dplyr")
library("haven")
library("tidyverse")
library("ggplot2")
library("plotly") 

df <- data.frame(
  SUBJID = c("101-001", "101-001", "101-001", "101-001", "101-001", "101-002", "101-002", "101-006", "101-006", "101-007", "101-007", "302-001", "302-001", "303-001", "303-001", "303-001"),
  ADY = c(-4, 37, 78, 121, 163, -7, 41, -20, 38, -7, 42, -10, 42, -14, 41, 78),
  PCHG = c(0, 0, -12.444523, -12.444322, -25.482626, 0, 15.789474, 0, -3.22666, 0, 7.55533, 0, 18.076923, 0, -2.53434, 22.666667),
  TRTA = c("6mg", "6mg", "6mg", "6mg", "6mg", "12mg", "12mg", "24mg", "24mg", "24mg", "24mg", "40mg", "40mg", "40mg", "40mg", "40mg"),
  TRTAN = c(11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15),
  BOR = c("PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PD", "PD", "PD", "PD", "SD", "SD", "PD", "PD", "SD", "SD", "SD")
)

shinyUI(navbarPage(
  "Patient Profiles",
 
  tabPanel(
    "Spider Plot",
    fluidPage(
 
      uiOutput("selected_plot_trt"),
      plotlyOutput("plot", height = 800, width = 1800)
    )
  ),
  
  collapsible = TRUE
))

server.R
library("dplyr")
library("haven")
library("tidyverse")
library("ggplot2")
library("plotly") 

df <- data.frame(
  SUBJID = c("101-001", "101-001", "101-001", "101-001", "101-001", "101-002", "101-002", "101-006", "101-006", "101-007", "101-007", "302-001", "302-001", "303-001", "303-001", "303-001"),
  ADY = c(-4, 37, 78, 121, 163, -7, 41, -20, 38, -7, 42, -10, 42, -14, 41, 78),
  PCHG = c(0, 0, -12.444523, -12.444322, -25.482626, 0, 15.789474, 0, -3.22666, 0, 7.55533, 0, 18.076923, 0, -2.53434, 22.666667),
  TRTA = c("6mg", "6mg", "6mg", "6mg", "6mg", "12mg", "12mg", "24mg", "24mg", "24mg", "24mg", "40mg", "40mg", "40mg", "40mg", "40mg"),
  TRTAN = c(11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15),
  BOR = c("PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PD", "PD", "PD", "PD", "SD", "SD", "PD", "PD", "SD", "SD", "SD")
)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session){


    plot_data <- df %>% 
      select(SUBJID, ADY, PCHG, TRTA, TRTAN, BOR) %>% 
      arrange(TRTAN)
 
  output$selected_plot_trt <- renderUI({
    selectInput("selected_plot_trt",
                "Treatment Group",
                choices = c("All", unique(sort(c(as.character(plot_data$TRTA))))))
  })

  
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
  
      if (input$selected_plot_trt != "All") {
       plot_data <- plot_data[plot_data$TRTA == input$selected_plot_trt, ]
      }
    
    ggplotly(
      ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = ADY, y = PCHG, group = SUBJID, color=reorder(TRTA, TRTAN)
                                 ))  +
        theme_bw(base_size=12) +
        ggtitle("Percent Change in Tumor from Baseline over Time") +
        theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
        xlab("Analysis Relative Day") +
        ylab("Percent Change from Baseline") +
        geom_line() +
        geom_point(aes(shape = BOR, color=BOR), size = 2) +
 
        scale_color_manual(name="",
                           values = c("6mg" = "#B03060", "12mg" = "#d62728",  
                                      "24mg" = "#2ca02c","40mg" = "#ffbb78"),
                           
                           breaks = c("6mg", "12mg", "24mg", 
                                      "40mg"),
                           
                           labels = c("6mg", "12mg",  "24mg", 
                                      "40mg")) +
        
        scale_shape_manual(name = "",
                           breaks = c("CR", "PR", "SD", "PD", "NA"),
                           values = c("SD"=16, "PD"=4, "PR"=18, "CR"=17, "NA"=4),
                           labels=c("CR"="Complete Response", "PR"="Partial Response",
                                    "SD"="Stable Disease", "PD"="Progressive Disease", "NA"="Not Available"))
      )
  })
 
})


wondering what's causing the warning and how to get rid of it?
Thanks!!

Perhaps try setting a default value for your selectInput with selected = [your default].

My Shiny is pretty rusty, but I'd expect the selectInput to show up in the UI, not the server... Not sure if that is related to your problem, but is there a reason you're doing it this way?

Use req() to eliminate your warning.
output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    req(input$selected_plot_trt)
    if (input$selected_plot_trt != "All") {
      plot_data <- plot_data[plot_data$TRTA == input$selected_plot_trt, ]
    }
    
    ggplotly(
      ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = ADY, y = PCHG, group = SUBJID, color=reorder(TRTA, TRTAN)
      ))  +
        theme_bw(base_size=12) +
        ggtitle("Percent Change in Tumor from Baseline over Time") +
        theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
        xlab("Analysis Relative Day") +
        ylab("Percent Change from Baseline") +
        geom_line() +
        geom_point(aes(shape = BOR, color=BOR), size = 2) +
        
        scale_color_manual(name="",
                           values = c("6mg" = "#B03060", "12mg" = "#d62728",  
                                      "24mg" = "#2ca02c","40mg" = "#ffbb78"),
                           
                           breaks = c("6mg", "12mg", "24mg", 
                                      "40mg"),
                           
                           labels = c("6mg", "12mg",  "24mg", 
                                      "40mg")) +
        
        scale_shape_manual(name = "",
                           breaks = c("CR", "PR", "SD", "PD", "NA"),
                           values = c("SD"=16, "PD"=4, "PR"=18, "CR"=17, "NA"=4),
                           labels=c("CR"="Complete Response", "PR"="Partial Response",
                                    "SD"="Stable Disease", "PD"="Progressive Disease", "NA"="Not Available"))
    )
  })

